# How to host a WPF form in a MFC application

Tags: c#, wpf, mfc

I'm looking for any resources on hosting a WPF form within an existing MFC application.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand (haven't tried myself), it's almost as simple as just giving the WPF control the parent's handle. Here's a [Walkthrough: Hosting WPF Content in Win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-wpf-content-in-win32).

Comment: But the example uses c++/cli and not mfc. Can’t this answer be expanded?